# Symfony2 Bad Credentials Error

Tags: php, symfony, authentication

I am fairly new to the Symfony2 framework, however I have learnt a lot in the short time I have been using it. I am currently trying to create a registration/login system but I am constantly getting the "Bad Credentials" error when I attempt to login. The registration works fine, from what I've read in researching this error it seems to be something to do with the Security.yml page in the encoders section.

I have been looking on the Symfony2 documentation, Stack Overflow, blogs and other resources for an answer to this issue, however everything I try doesn't seem to work. My code is below. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

My code is below, thank you in advance.

My Security.yml

```
security:
encoders:
    Acme\AccountBundle\Entity\User:
        algorithm:        sha1
        encode_as_base64: false
        iterations:       1


role_hierarchy:
    ROLE_ADMIN:       ROLE_USER
    ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN: [ROLE_USER, ROLE_ADMIN, ROLE_ALLOWED_TO_SWITCH]

providers:
    in_memory:
        memory:
            users:
                user:  { password: userpass, roles: [ 'ROLE_USER' ] }
                admin: { password: adminpass, roles: [ 'ROLE_ADMIN' ] }

encoders:
    Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\User: plaintext


providers:
    main:
        entity:
            class: Acme\AccountBundle\Entity\User
            property: username

firewalls:
    dev:
        pattern:  ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
        security: false

    login:
        pattern:  ^/demo/secured/login$
        security: false


    secured_area:
        pattern:   ^/
        anonymous: ~
        form_login:
            login_path: login
            check_path: login_check
        #anonymous: ~
        #http_basic:
        #    realm: "Secured Demo Area"

access_control:
    #- { path: ^/login, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY, requires_channel: https }
               - { path: ^/secure_area, roles: ROLE_USER }
```

My AccountController.php

```
<?php
namespace Acme\AccountBundle\Controller;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;

use Acme\AccountBundle\Form\Type\RegistrationType;
use Acme\AccountBundle\Form\Model\Registration;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;

class AccountController extends Controller
{
    public function registerAction()
    {
        $registration = new Registration();
        $form = $this->createForm(new RegistrationType(), $registration, array(
            'action' => $this->generateUrl('account_create'),
        ));

        return $this->render(
            'AcmeAccountBundle:Account:register.html.twig',
            array('form' => $form->createView())
        );
    }

    public function createAction(Request $request)
    {
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

        $form = $this->createForm(new RegistrationType(), new Registration());

        $form->handleRequest($request);

        if ($form->isValid()) {
            $registration = $form->getData();

            $em->persist($registration->getUser());
            $em->flush();

            return $this->render(
            'AcmeAccountBundle:Success:Welcome.html.twig',
            array('form' => $form->createView())
        );

        }

        return $this->render(
            'AcmeAccountBundle:Account:register.html.twig',
            array('form' => $form->createView())
        );
    }
}
```

My SecurityController.php

```
<?php
// src/Acme/SecurityBundle/Controller/SecurityController.php;
namespace Acme\AccountBundle\Controller;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\SecurityContextInterface;

class SecurityController extends Controller
{
    public function loginAction(Request $request)
    {
        $session = $request->getSession();

        // get the login error if there is one
        if ($request->attributes->has(SecurityContextInterface::AUTHENTICATION_ERROR)) {
            $error = $request->attributes->get(
                SecurityContextInterface::AUTHENTICATION_ERROR
            );
        } else {
            $error = $session->get(SecurityContextInterface::AUTHENTICATION_ERROR);
            $session->remove(SecurityContextInterface::AUTHENTICATION_ERROR);
        }

        return $this->render(
            'AcmeAccountBundle:Security:login.html.twig',
            array(
                // last username entered by the user
                'last_username' => $session->get(SecurityContextInterface::LAST_USERNAME),
                'error'         => $error,
            )
        );
    }
}
```

My User Entity

```
    <?php
namespace Acme\AccountBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;
use Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Validator\Constraints\UniqueEntity;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserInterface;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @UniqueEntity(fields="email", message="Email already taken")
 */
class User implements UserInterface
//this class is used for the table name
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     * @Assert\NotBlank()
     */
    protected $name;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     * @Assert\NotBlank()
     */
    protected $username;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     * @Assert\NotBlank()
     * @Assert\Email()
     */
    protected $email;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=32)
     */
    protected $salt;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=64)
     * @Assert\NotBlank()
     * @Assert\Length(max = 4096)
     */
    protected $password;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->salt = md5(uniqid(null, true)); 

    }

    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * Set email
     *
     * @param string $email
     * @return User
     */
    public function setEmail($email)
    {
        $this->email = $email;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get email
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getEmail()
    {
        return $this->email;
    }

    /**
     * @inheritDoc
     */
    public function getRoles()
    {
        return array('ROLE_USER');
    }

    /**
     * @inheritDoc
     */
    public function eraseCredentials()
    {
    }

    /**
     * Set plainPassword
     *
     * @param string $plainPassword
     * @return User
     */
    public function setPassword($assword)
    {
        $this->password = sha1($password);
    }

    /**
     * Get plainPassword
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getPassword()
    {
        return $this->password;
    }

    /**
     * Set name
     *
     * @param string $name
     * @return User
     */
    public function setName($name)
    {
        $this->name = $name;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get name
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getName()
    {
        return $this->name;
    }

    /**
     * Set username
     *
     * @param string $username
     * @return User
     */
    public function setUsername($username)
    {
        $this->username = $username;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get username
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getUsername()
    {
        return $this->username;
    }

    /**
     * Set salt
     *
     * @param string $salt
     * @return User
     */
    public function setSalt($salt)
    {
        $this->salt = $salt;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get salt
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getSalt()
    {
        return $this->salt;
    }
}
```

My Registration Model

```
<?php
namespace Acme\AccountBundle\Form\Model;

use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;

use Acme\AccountBundle\Entity\User;

class Registration
{
    /**
     * @Assert\Type(type="Acme\AccountBundle\Entity\User")
     * @Assert\Valid()
     */
    protected $user;

    /**
     * @Assert\NotBlank()
     * @Assert\True()
     */
    protected $termsAccepted;

    public function setUser(User $user)
    {
        $this->user = $user;
    }

    public function getUser()
    {
        return $this->user;
    }

    public function getTermsAccepted()
    {
        return $this->termsAccepted;
    }

    public function setTermsAccepted($termsAccepted)
    {
        $this->termsAccepted = (Boolean) $termsAccepted;
    }
}
```

The loginType.php

```
<?php
namespace Acme\AccountBundle\Form\Type;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolverInterface;

class UserType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder->add('username', 'text');
        $builder->add('password', 'repeated', array(
           'first_name'  => 'password',
           'second_name' => 'confirm',
           'type'        => 'password',

        )); 


    }

    public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => 'Acme\AccountBundle\Entity\User'
        ));
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return 'user';
    }
}
```

The RegistrationType.php

```
<?php
namespace Acme\AccountBundle\Form\Type;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;

class RegistrationType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder->add('user', new UserType());
        $builder->add(
            'terms',
            'checkbox',
            array('property_path' => 'termsAccepted')
        );
        $builder->add('Register', 'submit');
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return 'registration';
    }
}
```

The UserType.php

```
<?php
namespace Acme\AccountBundle\Form\Type;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolverInterface;

class UserType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder->add('email', 'email');
        $builder->add('password', 'repeated', array(
           'first_name'  => 'password',
           'second_name' => 'confirm',
           'type'        => 'password',

        )); 
        $builder->add('name', 'text');
        $builder->add('username', 'text');
    }

    public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => 'Acme\AccountBundle\Entity\User'
        ));
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return 'user';
    }
}
```

Comment: Is this really the min amount of code required to reproduce your problem?

Comment: First, are you able to go to login page? Can you login with users in memory? Why did you commented `{ path: ^/login, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }`? Second, I am not sure if `{ path: ^/secure_area, roles: ROLE_USER }` should work

Comment: Hi guys, this is the amount of code I thought I'd need to put on, because I have been trying to solve this problem for so long I am not quite sure where the solution may lie. I have looked at so many different resources that it really does seem the issue could be just about anywhere.

I can login to the page if I use Fixtures for my login, however that isn't very practical. That path was already commented out as standard by Symfony when I created the bundle, the secure_area path is something I created.